# Apache MaxServers not taking effect

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, httpd.conf, mpm-prefork

I edited my httpd.conf to have the following

```
StartServers          2
MinSpareServers       2
MaxSpareServers       4
MaxClients          150
MaxRequestsPerChild   0
```

but when I do a

`root@server [/usr/local/apache/conf]# ps aux | grep httpd | wc -l`

I get 65-75 processes.
Any ideas why the setting is not taking effect ?
I'm using prefork, in case that helps.

Comment: PS. For those curious, I tried using IfModule prefork, doesn't work as well.

Comment: Is your system under any load? It might just have spawned new httpd processes to handle the volume of traffic.

Comment: Yes, it under serious load, but merely because of the new spawned httpd's, it's overwhelming the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MaxSpareServers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/prefork.html#maxspareservers) merely tells Apache how many *idle* processes it maintains, while [MaxClients](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients) tells it how many clients it can serve at the same time and with the prefork worker, this means number of processes. So, in your case Apache can create up to 154 processes

Is it possible that you serve around ~70 clients at the same time or that requests doesn't finish normally for some reason, thus keeping the request alive?

Comment: You could try running 'ab' to try and saturate the server - though it appears the system is working exactly as it should - why try and break it?

Comment: I will try to play with MaxClients. I already have Nginx working as a proxy, that's why I'm trying to reduce the Apache instances.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the basics: did you restart apache after editing your config file?  You need to do that with

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful
```

or similar.  Apache won't use the new settings until you do that.

Comment: Of course I did.